# Preventing Plots From Overlapping in R

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

I found this interesting R tutorial over here: https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/

I made some of the plots from this tutorial:

```
library(plotly)

#plot 1
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[which(df$year==2007 & df$continent=='Asia'),]

fig <- plot_ly(df, type='pie', labels = ~country, values = ~pop, textposition = 'inside')
fig1 <- fig %>% layout(uniformtext=list(minsize=12, mode='hide'))

#plot2
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[which(df$year==2007 & df$continent=='Europe' & df$pop > 2.e6),]

fig <- plot_ly(df, type='bar', x = ~country, y = ~pop, text = ~lifeExp, name="",
               hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>lifeExp: %{text:.2s}<br>'),
               texttemplate = '%{y:.2s}', textposition = 'outside')

fig2 <- fig %>% layout(uniformtext=list(minsize=8, mode='hide'))

#plot 3
fig3 <- plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
        text = ~paste('Species: ', Species))

#plot 4

fig4 <- plot_ly(
  type='pie',
  values=c(40000000, 20000000, 30000000, 10000000),
  labels=c("Wages", "Operating expenses", "Cost of sales", "Insurance"),
  texttemplate="%{label}: %{value:$,s} <br>(%{percent})",
  textposition="inside")
```

The problem happens when I try to bring them all together using the subplot function:

```
subplot(fig1,fig2, fig3, fig4)
```

As we can see here, all the plots are overlapping each other:

[image]

I tried to look more into the plotly documentation, but it seems like the only way to avoid this problem is to manually and painstakingly adjust the margins, widths and borders so that these plots don't overlap.

- But is there a more "standard" way to prevent this from happening? Perhaps there is some option that can be used to specify this, such that they don't overlap?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `domain` in every plot and use the arguments `widths` and `heights` in `subplot` to manually arrange the plots like this:

```r
library(plotly)

#plot 1
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[which(df$year==2007 & df$continent=='Asia'),]

fig <- plot_ly(df, type='pie', labels = ~country, values = ~pop, textposition = 'inside',
               domain = list(x = c(0, 0.5), y = c(0.6, 1)))
fig1 <- fig %>% layout(uniformtext=list(minsize=12, mode='hide'))

#plot2
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[which(df$year==2007 & df$continent=='Europe' & df$pop > 2.e6),]

fig <- plot_ly(df, type='bar', x = ~country, y = ~pop, text = ~lifeExp, name="",
               hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>lifeExp: %{text:.2s}<br>'),
               texttemplate = '%{y:.2s}', textposition = 'outside',
               domain = list(x = c(0.5, 1), y = c(0.6, 1)))

fig2 <- fig %>% layout(uniformtext=list(minsize=8, mode='hide'))

#plot 3
fig3 <- plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
                text = ~paste('Species: ', Species),
                domain = list(x = c(0, 0.5), y = c(0, 0.4)))

#plot 4

fig4 <- plot_ly(
  type='pie',
  values=c(40000000, 20000000, 30000000, 10000000),
  labels=c("Wages", "Operating expenses", "Cost of sales", "Insurance"),
  texttemplate="%{label}: %{value:$,s} <br>(%{percent})",
  textposition="inside", 
  domain = list(x = c(0.5, 1), y = c(0, 0.4))) 

subplot(fig1,fig2, fig3, fig4, nrows = 2, widths = c(0.5, 0.5), heights = c(0.5, 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Please note: You can check the values to what you want to make sure it is fitted well.

Comment: @ Quinten: Thank you so much for your answer! I am still trying to understand how the "domain" argument works .... in this answer you have provided, suppose I want even more space between all 4 plots : both horizontal space and vertical space. How can I do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8, Np! With domain you can actually specify the position of your graphs. You can think about like domain(0,0) for example is left bottom. So what you can do is change the y coordinates of the domain so for the top graph you make the domain slightly higher and for the bottom graphs you can make the y domain slightly lower to create some space.

Comment: @ Quinten: Thank you again! If you have time later, could you please show an example of how I could use the domain statement to add some more space between these plots? Thank you again!